# Allow only two digits max in GET?

Tags: php

How do I check if there are only two digits maximum in `if(++$i > $_GET['number']) break;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use :

```
$number = intval($_GET['number']) ;
if( number >= 0 && <= 99 )
{

}

//OR
if( preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}$/',$_GET['number'] )
{

}
```

Comment: Ok but how to do it with in my if ?

Comment: complete the block of your code :) i.e. add your program ( the variable initial values )

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strlen($_GET['number']) > 2)
{
    ...
}
```